# Hive SerDe with "\u0000" as delimiter - can't get it to work

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-serde

I have a dataset similar to this:
[image]

SerDe sits on top of S3 location, and looks something similar to this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL     TABLE `default.ga_serde_test`(  
column1 string,column2 string
)   
ROW FORMAT SERDE    
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'    
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT  
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'  
 OUTPUTFORMAT   
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'    
 LOCATION   
's3a://xxxxxxx/inbound/xxx'
 TBLPROPERTIES (    
'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false',    
'numFiles'='0',     
'numRows'='-1',     
'quoteChar'='\"',   
'rawDataSize'='-1',     
'separatorChar'="\000",     
'totalSize'='0',    
 )
```

I tried \000, \0, ^@, NULL as seperatorChars - neither worked. Data is all loaded to the first column leaving second column empty.

Could anyone advise?

Comment: are you sure the file in S3 is a csv file? Looks to be either corrupted or in a different file format.

Comment: It's a CSV definitely. Delimiter is a bit weird I know, but this is how it looks like when opened in Notepad ++

Comment: Did you try to define `separatorChar` in `SERDEPROPERTIES`? I think its a `\\` by default.

Comment: @mazaneicha are you saying '\' will act as a null separator? I did try the Octal representation of Null ('\0', '\000') and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm trying to say it should be a serdeprop, not tblprop

Comment: Well spotted, however, it still doesn't work: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The separator character must be defined!'